# Print composer too many row in attribute table how to split in multiple frame?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

In the print composer, I've only added an attribute table and different attribute columns.

As I have too many row to display in a single page, I would like to split the table between different pages in the composer. With QGIS 3 I'am able to add other page in the same composer, this step is fine. I've also copy-pasted the table between those different pages, but now I'am stuck.

How can I do that? 
There is the option to limit to a certain number of row the display, but I can't manage to tell the newt table to start after the last row of previous table.

Comment: If you look at the 'item properties' tab for the attribute table, go to the 'frames' section and click 'add frame' - the text automatically flows into the next frame, which can be on the next page of the composer if you want

Comment: Thank you this is the exact answer I needed !

Comment: Good stuff - I use this quite a bit, and even used it to build a non-spatial list of our schools for a 'quick reference guide' - https://twitter.com/dpsspatial/status/1151953855766122497 the function is similar to 'text frames' in Scribus / InDesign